# QGiS 2.8.2 Graduated style symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, excel

I'm having trouble in QGIS with the symbology. I can classify and categorized my data, but I cannot with the graduated symbology?

I've try different format in Excel, and I can't find the problem here.

[image]